# How to filter results from mysql in node.js response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a query from MySQL selecting all columns with two rows. It returns a result as expected, but what I want is to store all rows fetched to `data`, like this:

```
var response = {
    data : result //result from mysql
};
```

But I don't want to display all the columns. Lets say the table has 4 columns.
The result from the MySQL query is:

```
[
    {
        row1: 'a', 
        row2: 'b', 
        row3: 'c', 
        row4: 'd'
    },
    {
        row1: 'e', 
        row2: 'f', 
        row3: 'g', 
        row4: 'h'
    }
]
```

And I only want to pass row2 and row3 in `response.data`. I want it to have a result of:

```
data : [
           {
               row2: 'b', 
               row3: 'c'
           }, 
           {
               row2: 'f', 
               row3: 'g'
           }
       ]
```

How to do that? Note that I do not specify in the MySQL query that it will only return row2 and row3, since that MySQL call will be used in other calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't want to change the actual `resopnse` object because you've specified that the result will be used in other calls.

I tried following using simple javascript.

```
var response = {data:[
    {
        row1: 'a', 
        row2: 'b', 
        row3: 'c', 
        row4: 'd'
    },
    {
        row1: 'e', 
        row2: 'f', 
        row3: 'g', 
        row4: 'h'
    }
]};

var newResponse = {};    
newResponse.data = response.data.map(function (rows) {
    return {row2:rows.row2,row3:rows.row3};
});

console.log(newResponse); //your result object as you wanted
console.log(response); // the actual response object, just to verify it doesn't got changed
```

Comment: Thanks! Works as expected.

Comment: I think @user3094292 meant to say he did not want to modify the SQL since that is used by other calls.  Modifying the response is exactly what we want to do in this case.  Making a dummy response just so we can call the map function is a little silly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [underscore map function](http://underscorejs.org/#map).

Like this:

```
var response = {};
response.data = _.map(result, function(row) {
    var newRow = {};
    newRow.row2 = row.row2;
    newRow.row3 = row.row3;
    return newRow;
});
```

Or you could simplify it with map and pick.

```
var response = {};
response.data = _.map(result, function(row) {
    return _.pick(row, 'row2', 'row3');
});
```